# How can I center my scrollbar contents in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a section of my app where the user is able to scroll through several widgets. My problem is that I can not figure out how to set the scrollable area (a tk.Frame) to resize its width to the parent frame. This is because the frame is placed into a canvas window, so grid() or pack() is never called, and therefore I can not use sticky=tk.EW. I should note that setting the canvas anchor=tk.CENTER also does not work.

Here's my code. self.workspace_frame refers to the parent frame:

```
    # Initialize scrollbar
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.workspace_frame)
    scrollbar.configure(
        orient=tk.VERTICAL,
        command=canvas.yview
    )

    # Initialize contents frame
    contents = tk.Frame(canvas)
    contents.configure(
        #background=self.receded_color
        background='red'
    )

    # Prevent resizing problems
    contents.bind(
        '<Configure>',
        lambda event: canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)
        )
    )

    # Configure canvas
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=contents)
    canvas.configure(
        yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,
        background=self.receded_color,
        highlightthickness=0
    )

    # Add elements to grid
    canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NS)
    scrollbar.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.NS)
```

Here is what my scrollbar and scroll area looks like. The red indicates the frame that I'm struggling to center: [My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfuLz.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the red frame (`contents`) to have same width as its parent (`canvas`), you need to resize its width after its parent is resized:

```
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: contents.config(width=e.width))
```

Comment: You're a life saver.